# List with dates, addHours to list linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime, entity

I have a **List with dates** to show it in a grid and I would like **add one hour to range2**:

```
private void grid_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = new List<EntityViewModel> 
    {
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 12, 0, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1983, 1, 1, 12, 23, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1985, 6, 14, 12, 0, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1990, 7, 3, 12, 23, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1995, 8, 1, 4,  23, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(1996, 1, 1, 12, 0, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 12) },
        new EntityViewModel { aDay = DateTime.Now }
    };

    var range = data.Where(i => i.aDay.Year >= 1983 && i.aDay.Year <= 1996).ToList();
    var range2 = range.Where(i => i.aDay.Date.IsDaylightSavingTime() == true).ToList();
}
```

**I tried this:**

```
var range3 = range.Where(i => i.aDay.Date.IsDaylightSavingTime() == true).ToList();
range3.ForEach(i => i.aDay.AddHours(1));
```

this:

```
foreach (var item in range2.Where(x => x.aDay != null))
{
    item.aDay.AddHours(1);
}
```

and this:

```
var range5 = range2.Where(i => i.aDay != null).Select(i => { i.aDay.AddHours(1); return i; }).ToList();
```

But it doesn't do anything, are always the same hour.

Comment: Given your code I would say that adding an hour for daylight saving is the wrong way to go, have a look at `ToUniversalTime()` instead and see if it does what you want. If it doesn't, have a look at `DateTimeOffset` as well, normal `DateTime` is not made to handle offsets. What `IsDaylightSavingTime()` does: Indicates whether this instance of DateTime is within the daylight saving time range for the current time zone. IE, even if you add an hour it will still state that it is daylight saving time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does NOT alter the initial date, but return a new one.
You need to select these dates:

```
var range5 = range2.Where(i => i.aDay != null).Select(i => i.aDay.AddHours(1));
```

To get the altered dates or

```
range3.ForEach(i => i.aDay = i.aDay.AddHours(1));
```

To alter the dates of the items in the list.

Comment: And if I want to take value away?

Comment: If you want to subtract an hour: `i.aDay.AddHours(-1)`

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is a structure, so you have to do:
`var date = DateTime.Now;
date = date.AddHours(1);`

in your case:
`range3.ForEach(i => i.aDay = i.aDay.AddHours(1));`

Answer (score 3):

AddHours returns a new DateTime, it does not change the current instance.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx

```
for (int i = 0; i < range2.Count; ++i) {
    range2[i].aDay = range2[i].aDay.AddHours(1);
}
```